# Hipervinculos en PyQt5 (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.7

Como puedo agregar un enlace en PyQt5 de manera que cuando cree un label que diga "Click Aqui" y al pulsar me lleve a la dirección que yo le asigne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se exactamente si quieres que se abra e link en el navegador por defecto del sistema o en la propia aplicación, supondré lo primero.

`QLabel` permite ésto sin problemas, un ejemplo:

```
import sys

#from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class TestApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(770, 627)
        self.setWindowTitle("Label Hiperlink")

        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.link_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.central_widget)
        self.link_label.setText(
            "<a href=\"https://es.stackoverflow.com//\">Click Aqui</a>"
            )
        self.link_label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.RichText)
        self.link_label.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextBrowserInteraction)
        self.link_label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        self.link_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 310, 58, 18))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Los pasos para conseguir dicho comportamientos del `QLabel` son:

- Le asignamos como texto el link envuelto en el código HTML pertinente.
- Para que renderize el texto como texto enriquecido  y no como texto plano, que nos mostraría el código HTML sin más, debemos especificarlo, eso es lo que hacemos con `setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.RichText)`.
- El siguiente paso es permitir que el texto se muestre y comporte como lo haría en un  `QTextBrowse`.
- Por último, por defecto el label emite la señal `linkActivated` cuando se activa el link. Para que se abra automáticamente en vez e emitir solo la señal hay que especificarlo con  `QLabel.setOpenExternalLinks(True)`, de forma que el link se abre automáticamente  usando `QDesktopServices::openUrl()`.

Comment: Esta bien ahi, Pero a que te referias cuando dijistes que abrilo en la misma aplicacion?

Comment: Puedes mostrar la página directamente en la aplicación, https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEngineView.html, a eso me refería.

Comment: ah ok, gracias de todas formas